# Data ends up with incorrect encoding when reading SQL from a .sql file instead of executing it in SQLite Browser

Tags: windows, encoding, sqlite, notepad++

I got this SQL statement that I wish to run on SQLite:

```
INSERT INTO tEntity (name) VALUES ('Roger Café');
```

Note the `é` character. Using the SQLite browser, I can insert this statement with the proper encoding.

However, if I save the above statement as a file (`my.sql`) and then run it on the Windows command line,  I am having an encoding problem. The `é` in `Café` is garbled up.

```
C:\somewhere> sqlite3.exe my.db
sqlite> .read my.sql
```

I'm using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to create the file in `ANSI` encoding. I have tried to use `UTF-8` encoding but `sqlite3.exe` gives me a `syntax error` while reading the SQL file.

Is there any solution to fix this?

Comment: Could you please trim your SQL down to the fields required to reproduce the problem?

Comment: How did you run in your console? Just tried the same thing but it seems to work.  care to show us your environment variables, too?

Comment: I save the sql statement using notepad ++ in ANSI mode. Then in the console,.read the sql file. I am just using a plain sqlite3 in windows

Comment: What kind of error did you get when you tried utf-8 with notepad++? I assume your .sql file has different encoding. (I have no idea about windows, but `é` worked on my linux box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding `UTF-8` in notepad++ has [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), which sqlite3.exe does not know about. Try using `UTF-8 without BOM`.

Comment: ok it works now, after converting everything to UTF-8 without BOM. Arigato Gozaimasu